# File size upload restrictions in Django when using Django-filer

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, django-file-upload, django-filer

I have no idea where else to post this,  I am using django-filer (https://django-filer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and running into limits when trying to upload files.  The problem is the software fails silently and does not give any errors and acts like it uploaded just fine.

While I understand Django-filer is niche (no support forums it seems), I am trying to figure out where to start looking to even begin to trouble shoot my file over 2GB not being uploaded.  I guess I should say it doesn't fail silently, but the errors I see in the var/log/httpd/error_log do not really make sense to me:

```
[Wed Mar 15 16:19:16.107217 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15399] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.20.0.80:43660] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: https://somesite.com/admin/filer/folder/23/list/?order_by=-modified_at
[Wed Mar 15 16:19:16.107234 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15399] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.20.0.80:43660] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: https://somesite.com/admin/filer/folder/23/list/?order_by=-modified_at
[Wed Mar 15 16:19:16.614657 2017] [:info] [pid 16476] mod_wsgi (pid=16476): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 15 16:19:17.235272 2017] [:info] [pid 16476] mod_wsgi (pid=16476): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Mar 15 16:19:17.236272 2017] [proxy:debug] [pid 16476] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Wed Mar 15 16:19:17.236298 2017] [proxy:debug] [pid 16476] proxy_util.c(1885): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Wed Mar 15 16:19:17.236353 2017] [proxy:debug] [pid 16476] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 16476 for (*)
[sthomas@sw-webserver swsite]$ sudo tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Wed Mar 15 15:21:20.544340 2017] [:error] [pid 15367]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
[Wed Mar 15 15:21:20.544343 2017] [:error] [pid 15367]     return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
[Wed Mar 15 15:21:20.544346 2017] [:error] [pid 15367]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
[Wed Mar 15 15:21:20.544350 2017] [:error] [pid 15367]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[Wed Mar 15 15:21:20.544353 2017] [:error] [pid 15367]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
[Wed Mar 15 15:21:20.544357 2017] [:error] [pid 15367]     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
[Wed Mar 15 15:21:20.544360 2017] [:error] [pid 15367]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
[Wed Mar 15 15:21:20.544363 2017] [:error] [pid 15367]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[Wed Mar 15 15:21:20.544366 2017] [:error] [pid 15367] DataError: integer out of range
```

So I see there is an error, looks like from the database?  But I am not sure what exactly is the reason for this and again no forums on djang-filer specifically.

So not sure where to look next to begin trouble shooting this.

The site works with smaller files...

Comment: For a start, if using mod_wsgi, your version of mod_wsgi is likely too old. Upgrade to the latest mod_wsgi version, which doesn't have the 2GB size limit. With older versions, attempts to upload more than 2GB would give unpredictable results.

Comment: okay I will get my sys admin to upgrade that on our centos box.  Thanks, I wasn't sure where to start looking